# Finding partial text string matches between two columns

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, partial-matches

I have a list of values in Column A (test), and a list of values in Column B (test 2). Many names in Column B contain a partial match with at least 1 value in column A.

Example:

Column A
Global Investors

Column B
Global Investors Capital

What kind of formula could I run that could show me the location of a partially matched value in column A?

Comment: what do you mean by "show location" ??

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA("A"&MATCH(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B2:B), 
 LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(A2:A, 1, 0))))), A:A, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

---

for jump link you can do:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B2:B="",,HYPERLINK("#gid=151561529&range="&
 IFNA("A"&MATCH(IFNA(REGEXEXTRACT(LOWER(B2:B), 
 LOWER(TEXTJOIN("|", 1, SORT(A2:A, 1, 0))))), A:A, 0)), "jump")))
```

[image: 0]

where you just change a **#gid** of the sheet

Comment: Thank you! This makes perfect sense. What happens if there are more than one potential match in Column A? Is it returning first value? Or is there a way to return multiple?

Comment: "Error
Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in C3." This is the error I get. Also, what is the red lettering for in the formula you shared?

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-Zvkq-5pOYf2BArNJD0usWvbwNIbLSd_Z4aMYPlvNUg/edit